# Web Services with Netbeans

Tags: web-services, deployment, soap, netbeans

After having done a web service with netbeans and having tested it. What is it that I should upload to the server so I can use it? I have been going around tutorials but none (of the ones I've found) say what to upload. They just finish when you deploy the web service =/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, you'll package it as a WAR file and deploy that to the app server.  A WAR file is what you need.

How you deploy depends on your situation and your app server.  If you're using Tomcat, you can either put the WAR in the /webapps directory or use the admin console to deploy.

If you're using a hosting service, you'll have to ask them how to do it.

Comment: so I just upload the .war file and I can access the web service linking to it? or what else do I need to do? I'm sorry I really have no idea...

Comment: If I deployed foo.war to Tomcat on myserver listening on port 8080, the URL I'd type into browser to see the WSDL for service bar might be http://myserver:8080/foo/bar.wsdl.  You'll have to figure it out for your case.